# Disprove: If $ f_n , f $ are differentiable and $ f_n \to f $ uniformly, then $ f_n' \to f' $ ( pointwise )

Tags: uniform-convergence

**Prove\Disprove:** If $ f_n , f $ are differentiable and $ f_n \to f $ uniformly, then $ f_n' \to f' $ ( pointwise ).

I was told the theorem is false but I couldn't come up with an example. Can you please help? how would you find an example that satisfies all the assumptions in question like this, is there some sort of rule-of-thumb I don't know about?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410420/42969

Comment: The standard counterexample is $\frac{\sin nx}{n}$.

Comment: A "theorem" cannot be false; it would not be called a "theorem" if it is false in the first place. A "statement" can be false. If you are learning real analysis, the corrected version of this statement should be a very standard theorem in the book.

Comment: @squid What's the corrected version of this statement? the one in the link above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f_n(x) = \frac{sin {nx}}{n}$ with $f(x) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of a previous counterexample! $f_{n}(x)=x^{2}\dfrac{sinnx}{n}$. It is clear that $f_{n}(x)\to 0$ pointwise and $sup_{[0,1]}|f_{n}(x)-0|\to 0$. But $f_{n}'(x)=2x\dfrac{sinnx}{n}+x^{2}cosnx.n.\dfrac{1}{n}$=

=$2x\dfrac{sinnx}{n}+x^{2}cosnx$ and clearly $f_{n}'(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)=0$.