# Partial derivative of a recursive function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

There are two functions:$$f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$$and$$g(z):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}.$$Both are differentiable.

I have a function $G(x)=g(f(x,G(x)))$. I want to take the derivative with respect to $x$. Is this possible? If so, how should I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: What is in "..."? If it is repeated "forever", then you would have a convergence issue of taking derivative under the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment - yes it would be "forever" repeating g(f(x,g(f(..),)))). Do you mind pointing me to a resource that covers such convergence issue?

Comment: Then it would only make sense to define $G$ as a limit. Where is this problem from?

Comment: For convergence, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410406/conditions-for-convergence-of-derivatives-from-pointwise-convergence

Comment: this is from an economics problem I am trying to conceptualize - mass of market participants (f) care about price (x) and a "congestion" variable (g) that depends on mass of market participants (f) (which again depends the same price, and the congestion as a function of other market participants, etc...))

Comment: Your recursion can be written as $G(x) = g(f(x, G(x)))$.

Comment: So $G(x)=g(f(x,G(x)))$ ?

Comment: Yes - it can be written as so. Thanks for clearing this up. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is convergent (which would be hard to prove) and that the limit and differential are interchangable (same issue) then you could say:
$$G'(x)=\frac{dG}{dx}=\frac{dG}{df(x,G)}\frac{df(x,G)}{dx}
\\=g'(f(x,G))\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial G}\frac{dG}{dx}\right]
\\=g'(f(x,G))\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial G}G'(x)\right]$$
rearranging you get:
$$\left[1-g'(f(x,G))f_G(x,G)\right]G'(x)=g'(f(x,g))f_x(x,G)$$
and here at least $G'$ is isolated but I am not sure this will lead you anywhere. Depending on the functions $f,g$ it may be that you can explicitly define $G$ and avoid all of this

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between $g'(f(x,G))$ and $g'(f(x,g))$? Also, what do you mean by i can avoid all this - if I have an explicit, well-behaving functional form of $G$, is this recursion not necessary?